Let P be a point inside a convex polygon. Prove that there exists a secant of this polygon such that P is its midpoint.
To clarify, secant of the polygon means a line segment with endpoints on the sides of the polygon.
I've discovered that P is the midpoint of the secant if and only if the lenght of this secant is the lowest from all of the secants that pass through P, but i failed to prove that, i guess this is a key idea in this problem since it was in problem set about derivatives.
Thank you for your help!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
